# Multiple Image Thumbnails Selector with SHIFT

Tags: php, jquery

Let's say I have a list of 1000 images in a folder on the server. I want to have a plugin or a way to show the thumbnails of those pictures, but the main thing is to have a way to SELECT the first 500 pictures. So I click the first one and then `SHIFT-CLICK` the 500th. So everything in between is then selected fast. Is there a plugin that could do that, jQuery or other?